# Flutter: How to create a CustomScrollView with items vanish/appear smoothly

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I want a `CustomScollView` with flexible Header where the items while scrolling vanish/appear smoothlyt by overlaying the top and bottom limit of the `SliverList` with a gradient that ranges from transparent to the color of the rest of the page.
Like in the this schematic layout.

[image: Layout]

At the bottom this was possible without any problems by placing the `Container` with the gradient inside a `Stack` with overlap=true and positioning it outside the Stack.

I tried the same inside the `SliverAppBar`'s `flexiSpace` but it did not allow that the gradient container overlapped its limits instead it was clipped.

Is there an easy way to accomplish it? I found a solution by using a `Stack` around everything and position the gradient container there by listening to the moving of the flexispace but that seems a bit cumbersome.